# git opens vim after pull - what happened?

Tags: git, vim, merge, message

Every time I make a pull (git pull), git opens a vim with message: [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`git pull` is equivalent to `git fetch` + `git merge` and `git merge` requires a commit message in a non-fast-forward case. `git` opens an editor for you to enter the commit message.

PS. Please copy/paste texts instead of putting images.

Comment: Ow, and how can I fix it?

Comment: What do you want to fix? Avoid merge? Or avoid editing message? Or do you want to call a different editor?

Comment: I want avoid editing message.

Comment: `git pull --no-edit`

Comment: Danke, sir. [15 characters here]

Comment: but how do we stop vim from opening up completely? I used to be able to add my comments in bash. vim popping up on a git merge just started happening to me. How do I revert to no vim?

Comment: In case anyone comes here with same issue
I'm still not sure what suddenly made vim the default editor in my IDE(Visual Studio Code). But anyway, THE SOLUTION TO NOT HAVING VIM launch when git merge was to change default editor to vscode. I thought I could just REMOVE vim from the .gitconfig file but it wasn't even there.
These are the commands I ran command line:

    git config --global merge.tool vscode

`git config --global mergetool.vscode.cmd "code --wait $MERGED"

git config --global diff.tool vscode

git config --global difftool.vscode.cmd "code --wait --diff $LOCAL $REMOTE"`

Comment: Oh actually,  ran the above 4 commands and then this one

            `git config --global core.editor "code --wait"`

Honestly I don't know if I needed all 5 commands but it stopping opening vim and using vscode when performing a `git merge` after this.